# Why i cant retrieve the date from database

Tags: php, yii2

Okay first of all, I have checked many questions on stackoverflow and those questions doesn't seems to solve my problem. Before some of you might put this question into a duplicate question, Can I have any explanation whats wrong with my code.

I want to calculate the days between two dates and the dates is being retrieved from database. 
Below is what I have done

```
if($model->save()){
    $date1 = strtotime($startDate);
    $date2 = strtotime($endDate);

    $days = ($date2 - $date1);
    $Days = ($days/(60*60*24));
    $model->no_of_days= $Days;
    $model->save();

}
```

`$startDate` and `$endDate` are being retrieved from the database. When I code it like this, the result is `0`.

but, when I replace it with a date, for example, `'2020-10-10'` and `'2020-10-13'`, the result is `3`.

My format for the date from the database is the same like the replaced date. Can someone guide me and explain to me. 
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: could you show a `var_dump()` for `$date1` and `$date2`

Comment: How do you get `$startDate` and `$endDate`? Are they the same maybe? Are they set at all?

Comment: `$startDate` and `$endDate` is from the user input @kerbholz

Comment: @jibsteroos im sorry, i didnt declare any `var_dump()` function

Comment: please show $date1 and $date2. dd("Date 1 is :".$date1."  Date 2 is : ".$date2);

Comment: ```var_dump``` is a built in PHP function that shows you the contents of one or more variables.

Comment: @Oops the `$date1` and `$date2` is for the data from the database

Comment: @Kyrre where can i find it in yii2 framework? im really sorry because im very new in php and mvc pattern

Comment: @Aech We understood that $date1 and $date2 are data in the database. To make sure that the date format is exactly same as that you are saying, we asked you to dump and die.

Comment: Please read the comments: [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a native PHP function, you can use it irrespective of the framework you're using.

Answer (score 2):

**Step One:** I suggest to avoid using `days`and `Days`as variables.

**Step Two:** Verify the content of `$startDate` and `$endDate`by dumping them with the native [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function.

```php
var_dump($startDate);
var_dump($endDate);
```

If data from your database are 'good', you should have the correct result. So we think that your $startDate and $endDate are not well initialized.

```php
    $date1 = strtotime('2020-10-10');
    $date2 = strtotime('2020-10-13');
    $days = ($date2 - $date1);
    var_dump($days); //returns 259200
    $days = ($days/(60*60*24)); 
    var_dump($days); //returns 3
```

You code should be:

```
if($model->save()){
        $date1 = strtotime($startDate);
        $date2 = strtotime($endDate);

        $days = ($date2 - $date1);
        $days = ($days/(60*60*24));
        $model->no_of_days= $days;
        $model->save();

}
```

**Step3:**
I think you should have a look on [DatetimeInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class or [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function.

Comment: you show `$model->no_of_days=$Days;`. but where can i initialize the `$Days` variable?

Comment: upvoted for step 1 alone. not that something is wrong per-se with step 2 mind you, but step 1 is great  :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said,if the format of the replaced date is same as that of the date from the database you can try using the following:
**Note** :  *you are using $days and $Days variable. Use can use a single $days variable to store the date difference result and can use that variable for saving into database. I have changed using $Days into $days.*

```
if($model->save()){
         // Calulating the difference in timestamps 
         $days = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate); 
        // 1 day = 24 hours 
        // 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds 
        $days= abs(round($days/ 86400)); 
        $model->no_of_days= $days;
        $model->save();

    }
```

Comment: its still print `0` as the result.

Comment: Please check $startDate and $endDate by doing a var_dump() [var_dump($startDate); var_dump($endDate);] or type dd($startDate." ".$endDate); in your code and run, and see what you are getting.

Comment: why i am getting this?

`C:\wamp64\www\HRMS\controllers\LeaveapplicationController.php:99:string 'startDate' (length=9)
C:\wamp64\www\HRMS\controllers\LeaveapplicationController.php:100:string 'endDate' (length=7)

startDateendDate`

Comment: and if im doing like this `$startDate=strtotime('startDate');
            $endDate=strtotime('endDate');
            
            var_dump($startDate);
            var_dump($endDate);`

i got an error that show boolean false.

dude im clueless

Comment: @Aech you are getting boolean false because you are using startDate as string i. It should be a variable $startDate. Please do dd($startDate." ".$endDate); in your code and run and see what you are getting.

Comment: i have configure my config folder add the d() and dd(). but when i do dd(), got this error `Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: and when i use `VarDumper::dump($startDate)` which is from yii library, the output i got is `'startDate'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_diff`

```
  $date1=date_create($startDate);
  $date2=date_create($endDate);
  $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
  echo $diff->format("%R%a");
```

If you pass correct `$startDate` and `$endDate` it should works correct.
Hope this help to you.

Comment: i have done this code, but i got this error _date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given_

Comment: So might be issue in your date structure.